# Optimum redistribution algorothm

Tags: algorithm, optimization, load-balancing

Let's assume I have a bucket of identical items (n in number) distributed in identical buckets (m in number). The given distribution may or may not be fair/uniform. The goal is to write an algorithm that can uniformly redistribute these items by transferring some items. Each transfer has a cost associated with it, so the number of transfers must be minimum.

For example I have total 7 items in 3 buckets with this distribution. Input is a vector of size 'm' of number of items in each bucket with - 4, 2, 1

The solution would involve 1 transfer from bucket 1 to bucket 3 and the resulting distribution will look like - 3, 2, 2

Since n(7) is not perfectly divisible by m(3), this is the closest achievable uniform distribution.

Another sample case -
input: {1, 4, 5, 11}

output: {5, 5, 5, 6}

Number of transfer to get to the output: 5

I'm looking for some existing algorithms that can solve this problem statement. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what's the problem here. Every item from a position that has more than its fair share needs to be transferred to a position that has less than its fair share, and it doesn't matter to which one, the cost is the same. You only need to avoid useless transfers when the distribution is not exactly even and some positions have one item more than the others. There isn't much of an algorithm.

Comment: Circumscribing this in informal speech is easier than writing down an exact algorithm (even if there _isn't much of_) - more so if time complexity is taken into account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your use case doesn't necessitate putting much thought into the implementation, since the numbers are apparently small, it may sometimes be desirable to use an algorithm with a time complexity not essentially dependent on the number of items, e. g.:

```
import numpy as np

def dist(inp):
    inp = np.array(inp)
    m = len(inp)            # number of buckets
    n = sum(inp)            # number of items
    l = n//m                # low number in an output bucket
    h = (n+m-1)//m          # high number in an output bucket
    lo = inp < l            # buckets which need transfer to
    hi = inp > h            # buckets which need transfer from
    out = np.empty(m, int)
    out[lo] = l             # fill underfull buckets with low
    out[hi] = h             # fill overfull buckets with high
    out[~lo & ~hi] = inp[~lo & ~hi] # keep other buckets as is
    o = sum(out)            # check missing or surplus items
    if o < n: out[np.where(out == l)[0][:n-o]] = h  # adjust
    if o > n: out[np.where(out == h)[0][:o-n]] = l  # adjust
    return out
```